# ReactJS NodeJS: getting token from server

Tags: node.js, reactjs

i have just started using react and i am building api for react in expressJS and using react-router-dom for routing and i got stuck with routes like this /api/:token, before using react it was easy for example for password recovery i could just render token variable and perform post request with rendered variable like this

in server

```
router.get('/reset/:token', (req,res)=>{

    res.render('reset', {token: req.params.token})

})
```

and in client side

```
  <form action="/reset/{{{token}}}" method="POST" id="id">
```

but in case of react first i should fetch data from api/someroute (i am using axios as a matter of fact)  but what should i do when i do not know that "someroute", how can i perform password reset post request to check if someroute really exists when i am not rendering that someroute variable (password recovery token and someroute are the same)

Answer (score 1):

The /:token route in your frontend matches any arbitrary string that comes after the the forward slash. Therefore, when a user asks for a password reset, construct a reset token in your node.js app, and send it to the users email address interpolated into the url (in place of /:token). The user clicks the link and then you grab it from the uri with a function such as this in your frontend (crude but it works):

```
onSubmit = formValues => {
    const { search } = this.props.location;
    const rawParams = search.slice(1, search.length).split("&");
    const parsedParams = rawParams.map(element => element.split("="));
    const headers = {
      "access-token": parsedParams[0][1],
      "token-type": "Bearer",
      client: parsedParams[1][1],
      expiry: parsedParams[4][1],
      uid: parsedParams[7][1].replace("%40", "@")
    };

    this.props.editPassword(formValues, headers);
  };
```

The formvalues contains the new password that the user types in, and we get the token from the uri which he gets through his email.

Comment: i've seen some articles and i think i know how to do that what would be your advice should i use slash or question mark? like localhost:3000/reset?token="dgdgsdgsdgsd" ?

Comment: i mean req.query

Comment: Yes, use a question mark to indicate where the query string begins as per convention.